# Elixir is_range guard is not defined? What should I use?

Tags: elixir

I would like to use an `is_range()` guard.  For example:

```
def foo(bar) when is_range(bar) do
    # stuff
end
```

But `is_range` doesn't exist?  I'm using Elixir 1.0.5

I tried

```
def foo(bar) when Range.range?(bar) do
    # stuff
end
```

but this didn't work either.

What should I do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The type of functions you can use in guards is quite limited.

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html

A range is a Struct which are maps, so you can use the `is_map`
function.

```
 iex(1)> foo = 1..3
 1..3
 iex(2)> is_map(foo)
 true
```

A Range is a map that looks like `%{ __struct__: Range, first: 1, last: 3}`

However, there is a better way to accomplish what you want by using pattern
matching in function args rather than guards.

```
def fun(%Range{} = range) do
  Map.from_struct(range)
end
```

This will match only a Range Struct, not any map.

Answer (score -1):

To test if a value is a member of a range you can use `in`.

`def is_high?(number) when number in 50..100 do
  true
end`

This also works for checking membership of elements in lists

`def is_a_great_number?(number) when number in [5,7,11] do
  true
end`

I realize this wasn't your question but this is the answer I was looking for when I found this question.